# Angular 2: How to capture when browser restore/maximize

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, events, browser

I have an angular application that is using [angular2-grid component.](https://github.com/BTMorton/angular2-grid) I am facing an issue when I have a grid within a grid. To resolve that I need to repaint the screen when the browser restore/maximize button is clicked. How will my angular application know that the browser restore/maximize application has been clicked?

Answer (score 1):

This method is not so reliable since if there is something prevents the window to be full width, this will not work, like a browser debugger docked on the side.

```
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var screenWidth = screen.width;

        if (windowWidth === screenWidth) {
            alert("Maximize");
        } else {
            alert("Restore");
        }
    }, false);
```